# Trim strings in the View of a Grails application

Tags: grails

Here is a sample view in a Grails 2.3.9 application:

```
<label for="label-${formInput.id}" class="editable_textarea"   
id="label-${formInput.id}"> 
${formInput.label ? formInput.label : formInput.inputType.defaultLabel} 
</label>
```

I want to trim values from `formInput.label` and `formInput.inputType.defaultLabel` to remove any leading and trailing whitespace.  I tried this:

```
formInput.label ? formInput.label.trim() : formInput.inputType.defaultLabel.trim()
```

but it did not work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a bug in `String.trim()` (which is highly unlikely), I don't see how this wouldn't work:

```
formInput.label ? formInput.label.trim() : formInput.inputType.defaultLabel.trim()
```

BTW, you seem to be storing the label text in the model, which is somewhat unusual, do they need to be dynamic?